# How to drag tableview cell from one row to another row?

Tags: iphone

How to drag tableview cell from first row to fifth row?

Can this be implemented on an iPhone?

If yes, please advance me how to implement this.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1 if you have a specific problem after reading that, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` methods:

```
tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: 
tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

and set the `editing` property on the tableView to YES